# Can't adjust the size of input and output arrays while doing a Kalman Filter with pseudoranges data

Tags: python, numpy, gps, kalman-filter

I'm doing a project on Kalman Filtering. I have to use the pseudo-ranges coming from the viewed satellites. But the number of satellites viewed changes in time so sometimes the arrays of the jacobian and states variables can changes. I don't know how to deal with it as I have to use the the i-1 and i matrix.

Here is some code :

```py
#______________________________________________________________________
def h(Xs,X):
  """vecteurs d'entrée : position des satellites. Les 4 premiers seront utilisés dans un premier temps
      matrice de sortie : matrice[1,4] contenant les équations des pseudo distances """
  H= np.array([np.sqrt((Xs[:,0]-X[0])**2+(Xs[:,1]-X[1])**2+(Xs[:,2]-X[2])**2)+c*X[3]])
  print('calcul H ',H)
  return H
#______________________________________________________
def jh(Xs, X):
  """vecteur en entrée : 
  Xs : positions [x,y,z] des satellites
  X    : Vecteur d'état [x,y,z,Δt] calculé à l'étape précédente
  Matrice de sortie : matrice jacobienne du système d'équations cad jacobienne de dimension nbSat,4
  """
  #there will be some weirdo stuff here. It's because by just writing c at the end, the output would be [array[5],array[5],array[5],scalar(c)] now the output is what I need
  tmp = np.array(c)
  for i in range (1,len(Xs)):
    tmp=np.append(tmp,c)
  return np.array([(Xs[:,0]-X[0])/np.sqrt((Xs[:,0]-X[0])**2+(Xs[:,1]-X[1])**2+(Xs[:,2]-X[2])**2),
                    (Xs[:,1]-X[1])/np.sqrt((Xs[:,0]-X[0])**2+(Xs[:,1]-X[1])**2+(Xs[:,2]-X[2])**2),
                    (Xs[:,2]-X[2])/np.sqrt((Xs[:,0]-X[0])**2+(Xs[:,1]-X[1])**2+(Xs[:,2]-X[2])**2),
                    tmp[:]]).T
#______________________________________________________________________
def q(bruitB):
  """prend en argument les valeurs de la variance des données captées à l'instant
  retourne la matrice de covariance du bruit. Les bruits des différentes mesures ne sont pas corrélés entre eux"""
  return np.eye(len(bruitB))*bruitB
#______________________________________________________________________
def predictionX(F,X):
  """retourne la prédiction du vecteur d'état"""
  return F.dot(X)
#______________________________________________________________________
def predictionP(F,P,Q):
  """retourne la matrice de covariance de l'erreur prédite à partir de la précédente"""
  return F.dot(P).dot(F.T)+Q
#______________________________________________________________________
def gain(P,R,J):
  """retourne de le gain de Kalman"""
  """J0 =[[ 5.99092039e-01  6.89189981e-02  7.97708531e-01  2.99792458e+08]
          [ 2.18072986e-01 -2.54363881e-01  9.42201246e-01  2.99792458e+08]
          [ 6.12139719e-01  7.08011156e-01  3.52143675e-01  2.99792458e+08]
          [-2.54436938e-01 -7.13085558e-02  9.64456808e-01  2.99792458e+08]
          [-9.20738262e-02 -9.24447876e-01  3.70025047e-01  2.99792458e+08]]"""
  #return np.divide(P.dot(J),H.dot(P).dot(H.T)+R)
  return (P.dot(J)/J.dot(P).dot(J.T)+R)#(J.dot(P).dot(J.T)+R)
  #return np.matmul(P,J)/(np.matmul(np.matmul(J,P),J.T)+R)
#______________________________________________________________________
def estimationP(P,K,H):
  """retourne l'estimation' de l'erreur"""
  return P-K.dot(H).dot(P)
#______________________________________________________________________
def estimationX(X,K,H,y):
  """retourne l'estimation du vecteur d'état"""
  return X+K.dot(y-H.dot(X))
#______________________________________________________________________
x_e=np.array([0,0,0,0])
p_e=q(data[0].gps.bruitB)
```

Please note that the Jacobian is transposed at the end of func jh

```py
"""matrice de transition"""
F=np.eye(4)
"""first state vector that I chose [x,y,z,Δt] """
X=np.array([0,0,0,0.00000001])#Δt = 10ns
"""model noise"""
Q=np.array([[1,0,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0],
           [0,0,0.01,0],
           [0,0,0,0.000000001]])
"""Covariance de l'erreur P"""
P=np.array([[2*2,0,0,0],
           [0,2*2,0,0],
           [0,0,3*3,0],
           [0,0,0,0.0000001]])
```

```py
for iterator in data:
  #initialisations
  """pseudo-ranges"""
  y=iterator.gps.PRc
  """white noise of the pseudoranges"""
  R=iterator.gps.bruitB*np.eye(len(iterator.gps.bruitB))

  print(len(P))#4
  x_p=predictionX(F,X)
  p_p=predictionP(F,P,Q)
  print('x = ',p_p)
  H=jh(iterator.gps.Xsat,x_p)
  print('H = ',H)
  print('taille de H ', len(H))
  K=gain(p_p,R,H)
```

There are three versions for the return value of the gain function (gain).
The first two versions are giving this error :

*ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (5,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)*

The last one makes this :

*ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5 is different from 4)*

I think the matrix are alright, so there would be a problem about the code in the use of np.array. Indeed, the number of colums of Jacob and number of lines of P are the same : 4. So the multiplication should be possible...

**[edit]**

I think the problem comes from something I misunderstand with Kalman in this case. I'm trying to estimate the x,y,z position from the nsat satellites's pseudoranges.

But since we use the pseudoranges I don't get how we link the pseudoranges and x,y,z,t So here are the steps of what I think I'm doing and where I don't understand

- X is the state matrix that contains [X,Y,Z,Δt] from the previous step.
- F is the transition matrix which is identity4 as we don't need any derivation of the variables.
- P is the covariance matrix of the error computed in the previous step. Size is also 4*4 as it's the error between the computed [x,y,z,Δt] computed and the real position. Nothin to do with the pseudoranges then.
- Q is the cov matrix of the noise. But it's the noise of the pseudorange value, so it's size is [nsat,nsat] right ? Or is it the noise on the real estimated position ? But how can I compute it if I have the std of the error for each pseudorange ?

from that we compute :

- the prediction of the next state variables Xp=F multiplied by X
- the prediction of the error Pp = F P Ftransposed + Q but Q is not the right size...

we compute the Kalman gain K

and we compute the new position :

- X = Xp + K ... wait we should use the datas from the sensor here, but they are pseudoranges. How can we link the pseudoranges and cartesian position inside the kalman filter ?
- P = Pp - K H Pp

Answer (score 0):

It should work with varying number of satellites with no problem.

It's a bit difficult to debug your code without any data. I implemented the pseudo range estimator in MATLAB using a simple trace generator (assuming the world is just flat in the XYZ domain). The number of satellites changes between 4 and 14 in each iteration.

Please have a look at my code. Maybe you'll find some hints. 
I'll try to go through your implementation and find some mismatches.

```
function [] = main()

    c = 299792458; % speed of light

    [t, PosRef, PosSatArr, clockBias] = generateData(c);

    n = numel(t);

    % state
    X = zeros(4, 1); % X, Y, Z, clockBias

    % transition matrix
    F = eye(4, 4); 

    % covariance matrix
    P = diag([100^2 100^2 100^2 1]);

    % system noise
    Q = diag([60 60 60 1e-12]);

    sigmaR2 = 1e6;

    X_arr = zeros(n, 4);

    for i = 1:n

        % setting the measurement
        y = PosSatArr(i).PosSat;

        [NSat, ~] = size(y);

        R = diag(sigmaR2*ones(1, NSat));

        [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F); %Prediction

        [X, P, ~] = update(X, P, y, R, c, NSat); %Update

        X_arr(i, :) = X';
    end  

    figure;
    subplot(4,1,1);
    plot([t(1) t(end)], [PosRef(1) PosRef(1)], '-');
    hold on;
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 1));
    hold off;
    grid minor;
    title('Position X');
    legend('Ground Truth', 'Estimation');

    subplot(4,1,2);
    plot([t(1) t(end)], [PosRef(2) PosRef(2)], '-');
    hold on;
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 2));
    hold off;
    grid minor;
    title('Position Y');
    legend('Ground Truth', 'Estimation');

    subplot(4,1,3);
    plot([t(1) t(end)], [PosRef(3) PosRef(3)], '-');
    hold on;
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 3));
    hold off;
    grid minor;
    title('Position Z');
    legend('Ground Truth', 'Estimation');    

    subplot(4,1,4);
    plot(t, clockBias, '-');
    hold on;
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 4));
    hold off;
    grid minor;    
    title('Clock Bias');
    legend('Ground Truth', 'Estimation');
end

function h = geth(X, y, c)
    h = vecnorm(y(:, 1:3) - X(1:3)', 2, 2) + c*X(4); 
end

function H = getJacobi(X, y, c, NSat)
    ro = vecnorm(y(:, 1:3) - X(1:3)', 2, 2); %pseudoranges from the current state and the satellite positions
    H = [-(y(:, 1:3) - X(1:3)')./ro c*ones(NSat, 1)];
end

function [t, PosRef, PosSatArr, clockBias] = generateData(c)
    t=1:1000;

    clockBias = 0.00001 + 0.00000001*t;

    PosRef = [randn(2,1); 0]*1e4;

    PosSatArr = struct;

    for i=1:numel(t)
        NSat = 4 + randi(10);
        PosSat = [randn(NSat, 3) zeros(NSat, 1)]*1e4; % X, Y, Z, PseudoRange
        %PosSat(:, 3) = abs(PosSat(:, 3)); % if you want your Z to be positive

        Range = vecnorm(PosSat(:, 1:3) - PosRef', 2, 2); 
        PosSat(:, 4) = Range + c*clockBias(i); 

        PosSatArr(i).PosSat = PosSat;
    end
end

function [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F)
    X = F*X;
    P = F*P*F' + Q;
end

function [X, P, K] = update(X, P, y, R, c, NSat)

    h = geth(X, y, c);
    H = getJacobi(X, y, c, NSat);    

    Inn = y(:, 4) - h;
    S = H*P*H' + R;
    K = P*H'/S;

    X = X + K*Inn;
    P = P - K*H*P;
end
```

The estimator works fine:
[image: GPS pseudo range estimator for positioning in a 3D space]

By the way, I think there is an error in your Jacobi Matrix. The last element should be `c`.

**UPDATE**

Here are some formulas for the Kalman Filter:

The state vector

[image: State vector for the pseudorange estimator]

The transition matrix is an identity matrix cause we don't change the state vector on prediction step

[image: F matrix]

Q is the system noise matrix. It has the size `[n x n]`, where `n` is the size of the state vector. It shows how much uncertainty is added to the state during prediction step. The smaller the values, the faster converges the filter (but maybe to a wrong state).

[image: Q matrix]

Each time the receiver communicates with the satellites it gets following information:

[image: Satillite information received by the receiver]

It's a little bit tricky. This is not the measurement vector for the Kalman filter. The first three columns are additional informations to calculate the measurement function and the Jacobi matrix.

The measurement `y` (in the Kalman sense) consists only of the pseudoranges:

[image: Measurement vector with pseudoranges]

The measurement function maps the state vector to the measurement. It tells you what measurement would look like to correspond to the currently estimated state. This is the connection between the pseudoranges and the estimated state.

[image: measurement function]

Jacobi matrix `H` needs to be calculated to linearize the non-linear measurement function `h`:

[image: Jacobi matrix]

The noise of the pseudoranges is stored in the matrix `R` (not in `Q`):

[image: pseudorange noise]

Comment: wow thank you very much for that answer. So I have to precise that what I tried here is the minor square method, just to be sure that everything works before implementing Kalman.

Comment: I added some explanations to the kalman filter. Does it answer your last questions?

Comment: There was a bug in my code by the innovation calculation. We are using the extended Kalman Filter here, so the innovation should be calculated using the measurement function and not using the Jacobi matrix as I did before. Now the estimation works perfect!

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me to understand but there is still something I don't get. P is the covariance of the estimation. So it should be the same size than the Jacobian right ? Else it can't be compute HPH'. I thought P shoud be a diag matrix size [n,n] with n the size of the state vector, but it can't be multiplied with Jacobi of size [5,4]. It should. But numpy says nope : 
ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (5,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Comment: let's say the state vector is [n, 1] and the measurement is [m, 1]. Then P is [n, n] and H is [m, n]. And HPH' would be  [m, n][n, n][n, m] = [m, m]

Comment: This line looks strange for me: J.T.dot(J).dot(np.transpose(J.T)).dot(r). What should it be? H'HH''R? T is another symbol for transpose. So you   calculate transpose from transpose, don't you?

Comment: True. This was an weird error. I edited my question with the last code and identified the problem. PH is not a square matrix as it's [4,4][4,5], but HPH' is a square. Then PH/HPH' can't be done, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it works, the main error was in this line

`return (P.dot(J)/J.dot(P).dot(J.T)+R)#(J.dot(P).dot(J.T)+R)`

We can't just divide a matrix, we have to multiply by the inverted Matrix so this works :

`return P.dot(J.T).dot(np.linalg.pinv(J.dot(P).dot(J.T)+R))` 
for the computation of the gain